# Does setting view engine in ExpressJS cause res.render() to only look in views folder for templates?

Tags: node.js, express

Does setting this

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

always cause

```
res.render([path]);
```

to start in the `views` directory?  In other words, is the `views` directory always implied for res.render() after setting up the view engine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will make render look in 'views'

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.render

If you scroll down to application settings it will tell you the default setting for view is

```
process.cwd() + '/views'
```